# What is the size of my website?

Tags: web-hosting

My NPO's website is on a proprietary CMS that is totally managed from a browser. There is no access to cPanel or FTP. The SLA does not limit storage space or bandwidth - at least we are not approaching any limits. Is there a way to roughly determine or estimate size, RAM and storage space of the site?

Comment: Your website doesn't *have* RAM. It *uses* it and that will vary depending on what's going on.

Comment: Thanks, yes - the site doesn't have ram but uses it. I'm trying to estimate what I may need for a new hosting environment including disk space, actual RAM, etc.

Comment: They're not going to be using a lot of anything. Basic hosting will almost certainly cover their needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have shell access to the server, a control panel reporting this to you, or the ability to add your own web files (ilike a PHP or Perl script), then you will not be able to get this information. And even then, it may be a moot point as it sounds like you are using a SaaS platform. This means the CMS software is being universally offered to all of the host's clients. You are just taking up space in their database and maybe in a directory  if they store and binary files like images there. You aren't taking up physical space like a traditional website does with its server side files, images, etc.

Answer (score 5):

If you are wanting to get a rough idea of the size of the site in order to transfer the contents into an alternative CMS on another host then you could perhaps try downloading the site with a website copier (eg. [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/)) - if it is spiderable - in order to get a quick idea of the size of all the resources (content, images, videos, CSS, client-side scripts, etc.) and then add on the size and documented requirements of your new CMS.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of your CMS features, but if your CMS uses a database and you have direct access to that database, study the schema briefly and do a query such as `SHOW TABLE STATUS` and look at the data length of the table(s) that contain content and meta-data. Take the total plus any resources within the web space.

This is what I do. Otherwise, I am not sure.

Comment: Thank you. No such luck on the database access. Your answer is helpful in that I understand I really can't get an estimate without the database size.

Comment: Perhaps tech support can do the query for you and e-mail the results.